# read from file with space delimiter

Tags: java

hello guys I need help with reading from file with space delimiter. The problem is for example i got a text file the format as follows: id  name

example:

1 my name

how can I get the string together (my name) as the code I have tried would only get me (my). I can't change the delimiter from the text file

```
        while(myScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String readLine = myScanner.nextLine();
            String readData[] = readLine.split(" ");
            String index = readData[0];
            String name = readData[1];

        }
        myScanner.close();
```

Comment: index 2 will have the name in it and then you can simply concatenate the two (i.e. my and name to get the desired result).

Comment: hmm but if the name is just name and not my name then there will be error on the index 2

Answer (score 0):

If it's always just going to be *id* space *name* with nothing coming after it, then you can do this:

```
String readLine = myScanner.nextLine();
int split = readLine.indexOf(" ");
String index = readLine.substring(0, split);
String name = readLine.substring(split + 1);
```

This will only work if those are the only two fields though. If you add more fields after that there's no (general) way to determine where item two ends and item three begins.

Another way is to use `next`, `nextInt`, etc, to read out exactly what you want:

```
String index = myScanner.next(); //Or int index = myScanner.nextInt();
String name  = myScanner.nextLine().substring(1); //drop the leading space
```

That's a bit more flexible of an approach, which might be better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
    while(myScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String readLine = myScanner.nextLine();
    if(null != readLine && readLine.length()>0) {
        String index = readLine.substring(0, id.indexOf(" "));
        String name = readLine.substring(id.indexOf(" ") + 1);
    }

}
myScanner.close();
```